# How can I select users who have not submitted records using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have columns in my database for date_created (format 2014-07-08 11:25:29) and username. I want to create a conditional statement which will display users who have not submitted a new record within the last week. I've never really queried my database for an action NOT taking place. How might I achieve this?

Comment: `select * from users where date_created < '2014-07-08 11:25:29' or date_created is null`?

Comment: Do you have a separate table with all users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  username
FROM    records
GROUP BY
        username
HAVING  MAX(date_created) < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

Note, however, that this query won't return users who haven't created a single record.

If you have another table holding all user records (including those who had no records in `records`), use this query:

```
SELECT  u.username
FROM    users u
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    records r
        WHERE   r.username = u.username
                AND r.date_created >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
        )
```

In both cases, make sure you have an index on `records (username, date_created)` for the queries to work fast.

Comment: Can you explain your second code block to me? I'm not familiar with the syntax you're using, such as u.username and users u and records r. Does the letter become an alias for the object?

Comment: @KinsDotNet yes it does